# spaces not accepting in ListQuery while querying a list in Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to pass a query to a spreadsheet. I have a value say "John cena". How do I pass it in the following line. I am getting an error while doing so

```
ListQuery query = new ListQuery(listFeedUrl);
query.setSpreadsheetQuery("name = 'John cena' and age > 25");
ListFeed feed = service.query(query, ListFeed.class);
```

This is the error im getting:

```
com.google.gdata.util.InvalidEntryException: Bad Request
Parse error: Invalid token encountered

at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:594)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(GoogleGDataRequest.java:563)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.checkResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:552)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.execute(HttpGDataRequest.java:530)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.execute(GoogleGDataRequest.java:535)
at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1135)
at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1077)
at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.getFeed(GoogleService.java:662)
at com.google.gdata.client.Service.query(Service.java:1237)
at com.google.gdata.client.Service.query(Service.java:1178)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sorry I don't know the answer completely, but I want to help.

Can you try something like this:

```
query.setSpreadsheetQuery("name = \"John cena\" and age > 25");
```

The wiki post @ http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/data/3.0/developers_guide.html#SendingStructuredRowQueries says that you have to include data with space in quotations.

Comment: I have tried it. It dint work. I have tried different possiblities like giving it in single quotes, providing underscore, etc. I had similar problem with column name. But it did work when I provided it in all small letters without spaces. Say Full Name. I have given it as fullname. It worked for column names.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, where I had my item column with values that can contain white spaces. By adding double quotes and escaping it in string, I was able to bypass the issue. Also you might want to remove other spaces in the query, apart from the ones between "and", just in case.

```
String queryString = ""; //should contain feedURL
ListQuery lsListQuery = new ListQuery(new URI(queryString).toURL());
lsListQuery.setSpreadsheetQuery("item=\"Item Name4\" ");

\\This will have the URI encoded
logger.debug(lsListQuery.getQueryUri()); 
\\This will give you the complete URL
logger.debug(new URI (queryString+lsListQuery.getQueryUri().toString()).toURL()); 
\\ This should give the feed from which the columns can be read
ListFeed listFeed = service.getFeed(new URI (queryString+lsListQuery.getQueryUri().toString()).toURL(), ListFeed.class);
```